# Is it acceptable to make and accept my own answer in this case?

Tags: discussion

[How to draw a smoother solid-fill circle?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/176036/how-to-draw-a-smoother-solid-fill-circle)

@user1118321 submitted [an answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/176039/132878) that was useful but did not answer my question exactly; I did not want to use anti-aliasing for the edge of the circle. I've thanked him and suggested that he submit a different answer if it interests him.

I am also interested in @Pikalek's as-yet unsubmitted answer as he mentioned using an alternative method using the mid-point algorithm.

I have since updated my original post with an update on my progress instead of submitting it as an answer, even though I think it would qualify as "an answer".

My questions are:

- Pikalek played a role in my solution and I would acknowledge this in an answer if I submit one. It feels very rude but I do acknowledge his answer and state why it was insufficient. Is it acceptable to modify someone else's answer for my own and accept it **when I also asked the question**? The difference in code is subtle but the result is significant.
- I submitted my solution as an update to my question instead of rushing to answer it myself to not discourage others from submitting their own. I'm effectively baiting more answers with a solution in reserve. Am I wrong to manage my question in this way? If a better solution comes along, I will accept that instead.

I suppose that, while I do have *an* answer, I'm not satisfied with it. And since it is my question, I feel that my actions are justified.

I'm seeking advice on whether I'm handled this situation appropriately.

Comment: Have you though this situation from the point of view of a future reader? Imagine in a few months someone has the same problem as you, and they find your question, which answer would they need to read to solve their problem? I'm not sure about this specific case, but I'd say if an answer gives you enough "nudge" of what to do next and how to approach a problem, it's good enough. If anything, you can always edit an answer, if you feel it will make it more complete.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it acceptable to make and accept my own answer in this case?

I think it is.

The comment box says (emphasis mine):

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. **Avoid answering questions in comments.**

If a user posts an answer as a comment, then it could mean either:

- They don't have a full solution but still feel like helping you
- They don't have the time to write a full answer but still feel like helping you
- They're afraid to lose rep by posting a wrong answer
- Etc..

Nothing prevents another user to take that comment and turn it into an answer to reap the rep.

With the the reminder in the comments box, users knowingly forfeit these potential Internet points.

But that's just me.